# Google+ hangout Screensharing Resolution

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

Google+ hangouts are actually a reason to use Google+. The introduction of screen sharing, makes it that much more compelling to use it with work teams and small groups. Out of the box Google+ scales the shared screen so much that it's unreadable. Is there any way around this?